# how to fix Error: equest failed with status code 400 in react native google signin error 400?

Tags: react-native, react-google-login

To handle google signin, I'm using the @react-native-google-signin/google-signin package, which worked OK until the request failed with a status code of 400.
[image]

For requests, I use the following code.

```
const googleSignIn = async () => {
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.log(userInfo);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add some more description about the error? Also check if your webClient is correct.

Comment: currently when i try to login using google signin it returns 400 error. the code i use is the above one. i will check webClient. does webClient related with it?